# How to add a Customized WhatsApp Sticker from firebase into WhatsApp without Content Provider?

Tags: java, android, firebase, whatsapp-stickers

I got lots of java files and the mechanism for **adding** a sticker to **WhatsApp**. I'm working on memes app that include stickers as well. I wanna let the user add a **customized** sticker to WhatsApp. My app implements **Room**, View-Model, Repository Pattern and lots of features, so I got a snippet from WhatsApp source code for android that shows the **intent** action as well.
but I just wanna simple one so.

I just want to:

- load sticker from firebase
- store it in files
- change the extension to webp
- when the user clicks on the save button it would add it to WhatsApp.

I can do all the above steps but for the last one, I need simplified code to save it.
is there any way to add sticker without creating **Content Provider**

[WhatsApp Sticker Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cmpl.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot just change any image format to `.webp` just by changing extension.
You'll have to properly change the format.

Second,
a `ContentProvider` is the **most important** part here that will allow WhatsApp to communicate with your App to know about the sticker files (Images).
So No, you cannot just add a sticker pack to WhatsApp without implementing the appropriate `ContentProvider`.

Check the `ContentProvider` implementation [here](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerContentProvider.java) & change it according to your logic.

Comment: Okay, should I have implement all the logic or content provider only is sufficient?

Comment: @AhmedSaad You’ll have to change it if you will be fetching from network or something like that, if you use local images (added in assets) it will still require minimal changes.

Comment: Yea I know I just got the clone from WhatsApp Github and working on it just editing contents.json file so it serves only for assets. but I wanna a tutorial or documentation to add this sticker from the network or pick it from user gallery.

Comment: @AhmedSaad - have you got any tutorial or documentation to add sticker from user gallery?

Comment: It seems long to comment not yet @khushbuvadi